# Class composition, giving unkown override specifier error

Tags: c++

I am trying to use some of my methods in my App class inside of my Chart class, so I am using composition to create a private member (Chart chart) inside of my App class but I'm having some problems. Also, if I wanted to have that chart member be a nullptr until I need it in my code would I just do it like this `Chart* chart = nullptr;` and then right before I need to use it in my App class  `chart = new Chart;`

Here is my code, and these are the two main errors I'm getting `unknown override specifier`, `missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int`.

App.h

```
#ifndef APP_H_
#define APP_H_
#pragma once
#include <iomanip>
#include "Chart.h"
#include <conio.h>


class App
{
public:
    App();
    App(double, double, double, int);
    ~App();
    void mainloop();
    int getNumOfYears();
    

private:
    double investmentAmt;
    double monthlyDeposit;
    double annualInterest;
    int numOfYears;

    Chart chart; <-------- error here

    void display();
    void menu();
    void report();


                };
#endif
```

Chart.h

```
#ifndef CHART_H_
#define CHART_H_
#pragma once
#include "App.h"


class Chart {
public:
    Chart();
    ~Chart();
    void Display();
    void Display(bool);
    App myApp; <-------- error here

private:
    int numOfMonths;
    double openingAmt;
    double depositedAmt;
    double total;
    double interest;
    double closingBalance;

};
#endif
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve by `Chart` using `App` and `App` using `Chart`?

Comment: Please indicate which line of code gives the error. Also, `App` contains a `Chart`, and vice-versa? That's a circular dependency, and probably not what you want.

Comment: I want to use the Display methods from the chart class inside of the app class, and in the chart class i want to use the numOfYears getter.

Comment: Removing the `App` in `Chart` and make a function to input `numOfYears` to `Chart` is a way. Or let `Chart`'s constructor takes this argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code idea is very similar to the **observer** pattern. In order to avoid circular dependencies, you can try replacing one or more data members with pointer members or references as members.

You need to change your code to somewhat like this:

```
class Chart; // forward declaration for chart
class App {
  Chart* chart;
};

// And for another source file
class App; // forward declaration for App
class Chart {
  App* myApp;
};
```

Reference:

https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/observer/cpp/example

Comment: *In order to avoid circular dependencies, you can only use pointer members or references as members.* Not 100% true. You only need to break the cycle. Often (and this case looks like it applies) only one member needs to be replaced with a reference. Which one should be turned into a reference (or if an entirely different path should be chosen) depends on data not provided in the question.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for your remind, your suggestion is very good